Isekai mahwa with silver haired male lead who is an illegitimate prince
The fl is a noble lady who is unwillingly married to the ml. He lives in a countryside farm. The fl comes here with him but doesn't want to live here. Ml cooks and cleans. She doesn't do anything. He gives her comfortable clothes . They slowly start getting acquainted.

This could be Fallen to Paradise

Ange, the daughter of Duke Glaster, believes her life is all planned
out as she is set to marry Philip Cardiner, the rightful heir to the
throne. However, her plans are disrupted when Philip's brother,
William Cardiner, schemes against him and removes him from the line of
succession. In order to secure his power, William forces Ange to marry
Aiden Fitzroy, an illegitimate child born between the emperor and a
commoner. Will Ange learn to love the humble stranger she was forced
to marry?

White hair ML, lives in countryside, yada yada everything matches, though it's not isekai.


I'm about ten episodes in and I'm not seeing anything that would make this on-topic here. Is there any fantasy or magic happening, or is this just a mundane (albeit fictional) kingdom?

Yeah there's no magic/fantasy lmao, though I could def be wrong about what manhwa it is (it just REALLY sounded like it)

It's an excellent match to the question. If OP confirms it, the question is getting closed, though
